# Is there a way to connect the google classroom api to discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, google-classroom

I want to create a discord bot in python that sends a message whenever something is assigned. Is this possible?

Comment: use [The assigned notification part of the api](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/push-notifications) to get the json response and then send it as a message in discord.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found that for you. Check it
https://github.com/LuisVervaet/DiscordClassroom
download this project.